# JS: Create new unique instance of my plugin

Tags: javascript

I have created a JavaScript plugin, I'd like to have the potential to use this multiple times, however, having it called one the page twice like follows doesn't seem to make a new instance:

```
var lightbox = new MarvLightbox({ 
    imagesContainer: 'detail-hdr__detail-images',
    limit: 11
  });
  var lightbox2 = new MarvLightbox({ 
    imagesContainer: 'image-grid-2',
    galleryFolder: 2,
    mobileFolder: 0
  });
```

The following code seems to be returning the same values, so for example, if I click an image to set the `c` value within the `state` object then it's changed for instance `lightbox2` AND `lightbox`.

```
MarvLightbox.prototype.current = function() {
    console.log(state);
  };
```

I have tried to remove any none required code from my plugin. But what I'm basically doing is:
1. Compile a list of the images within a container. 
2. Generate HTML from a JSON string. 
3. Assigning click events to the images, and then when clicked they open the lightbox and change the image etc.

```
(function() {

  var instance = null,
      container;

  // Constructor
  this.MarvLightbox = function() {

    instance = this;

    // Create global variables
    this.images_count = -1;
    this.active = false;
    this.error = false;
    this.debug = false;

    // Define option defaults
    var defaults = {
      activeClass: 'marvLightbox',
      appendTo: '#wrapper',
      imagesContainer: null,
      thumbClass: null,
      lightboxId: 'marvLightbox',
      galleryFolder: null,
      mobileFolder: null,
      showAlt: true,
      showMax: true,
      limit: null,
      html: '{ "div": { "id": "{lightboxId}", "0": { "div": { "class": "{lightboxId}__container", "data-click": "EventClose", "0": { "div": { "class": "{lightboxId}__controls {lightboxId}__controls--top", "0": { "div": { "class": "{lightboxId}__eschint", "content": "Press <span>ESC</span> to close" } }, "1": { "div": { "class": "{lightboxId}__close", "data-click": "EventClose" } } } }, "1": { "div": { "class": "{lightboxId}__image", "0": { "img": { "src": "", "class": "responsive-img image", "data-click": "EventRight" } } } }, "2": { "div": { "class": "{lightboxId}__controls {lightboxId}__controls--bottom", "3": { "div": { "class": "{lightboxId}__left", "data-click": "EventLeft", "data-hover": "EventClass(#{lightboxId}, toggle: left)" } }, "4": { "div": { "class": "{lightboxId}__right", "data-click": "EventRight", "data-hover": "EventClass(#{lightboxId}, toggle: right)" } }, "5": { "div": { "class": "{lightboxId}__alt" } }, "6": { "div": { "class": "{lightboxId}__num" } } } } } } } }'
    };

    // Create options by extending defaults with the passed in arugments
    if (arguments[0] && typeof arguments[0] === "object") {
      this.options = extendDefaults(defaults, arguments[0]);
    }

    this.options.html = this.options.html.replace(/\{(lightboxId)}/g, this.options.lightboxId);
    // this.options.limit = this.options.limit + 1;

    // Check if debugging is enabled
    (function() {
      var args = document.querySelectorAll('[data-external-arg]');
      if(args.length > 0 && args[0].src.indexOf('marv.lightbox') !== -1) {
        if (args[0].dataset.externalArg === 'debug') instance.debug = true;
      }
    }());

    // Initialise plugin
    this.init();
  };

  // Debugging messages
  var debug = function(code, arg) {

    var args = function(n) {
      if (arg === undefined) {
        return '[arg undefined]';
      }

      if (arg[n] === undefined) {
        return '[arg undefined]';
      } else {
        return arg[n];
      }
    };

    var messages = function(code, argument) {
      return [
        'marv.lightbox(debug): Debugging mode is on, make sure you turn this off before you launch',
        'marv.lightbox(debug): HTMLElement(' + args(0) + ') with the name of ' + args(1) + ' has been detected',
        'marv.lightbox(debug): Found '+ arg + ' image/s within your Lightbox container ',
        'marv.lightbox(debug): ' + args(0) + ' key pressed, changing current (' + args(1) + '), number of images (' + args(2) + ')',
        'marv.lightbox(debug): Current is set to null, closing lightbox',
        'marv.lightbox(debug): Inserting Lightbox within HTMLElement(' + args(1) + '), using ' + args(0),
        'marv.lightbox(debug): 1 image found, don\'t add previous/next arrows, don\'t show numbers either',
        'marv.lightbox(debug): showAlt set to false, don\'t display alt text',
        'marv.lightbox(debug): showMax set to false, don\'t display numbers below alt text',
        'marv.lightbox(debug): Reverting to mobile version (' + instance.options.mobileFolder + ') of images',
        'marv.lightbox(debug): Over-riding to ' + instance.options.galleryFolder + ' version of images'
      ][code];
    };
    if (instance.debug === true)
      console.log(messages(code, arg));

  };

  // Error messages
  var error = function(code, arg) {

    var args = function(n) {
      if (arg === undefined) {
        return '[arg undefined]';
      }

      if (arg[n] === undefined) {
        return '[arg undefined]';
      } else {
        return arg[n];
      }
    };

    var messages = function(code, argument) {
      return [
        'marv.lightbox(error): I need to know which images to use... add { imagesContainer: "id/class" } to the plugin initialization',
        'marv.lightbox(error): The HTML structure provided appears to have an error: ' + arg,
        'marv.lightbox(error): Issue compiling list of images, speak to Dev, error: ' + arg,
        'marv.lightbox(error): Your going to need some images for this to work... make sure they have the class: ' + instance.options.thumbClass,
        'marv.lightbox(error): I was unable to find an element which matches ' + instance.options.imagesContainer + ', please double check this',
        'marv.lightbox(error): I was unable to find a container with the name of ' + args[0],
        'marv.lightbox(error): EventListener with arguments passed, had an issue seperating arguments, check formatting',
        'marv.lightbox(error): Unable to apply class event to element, please check your attribute',
        'marv.lightbox(error): You have attempted to over-ride the images folder with a size that doesn\'t exist, please choose a size between 0 and ' + arg
      ][code];
    };
    console.log(messages(code, arg));
  };

  var imageSizes = function(e) {
    var sizes = [ '344x258', 'full', 'large1' ];
    if (sizes[e] !== undefined) {
      return sizes[e];
    }
    error(8, sizes.length);
  };

  // Initilise the plugin
  MarvLightbox.prototype.init = function() {

    if (this.options.imagesContainer === null) {
      error(0);
      return;
    }

    container = (instance.options.imagesContainer).objectType();
    if (container === null || container === undefined) {
      error(4);
      return;
    }

    debug(0);
    setupLightbox();
  };

  // Generate HTML from JSON
  function buildHTML(json) {
    "use strict";

    var handleAttribute = function(element, attribute, value) {
      if (value instanceof HTMLElement) {
        return element.appendChild(value);
      }
      switch (attribute) {
        case 'class':
        case 'src':
        case 'id':
        case 'data-click':
        case 'data-hover':
          return element.setAttribute(attribute, value);
        case 'content':
          element.innerHTML = value;
          return;
          // other keys...
        default:
          console.log(element.tagName, attribute, value);
                       }
    };
    var htmlReviver = function(key, value) {
      // parse as element
      if (isNaN(key) && typeof value === 'object') {
        var element = document.createElement(key);
        var subValue;

        for (var attribute in value) {
          handleAttribute(element, attribute, value[attribute]);
        }

        return element;
        // move element from { index: { tagName: Element } } to { index: Element }
      } else if (!isNaN(key)) {
        return value[Object.keys(value)[0]];
        // leave property alone
      } else {
        return value;
      }
    };
    try {
      var htmlObject = JSON.parse(json, htmlReviver);
      return htmlObject;
    } catch (e) {
      error(1, e);
    }
  }

  // Manage item change
  var images_compiled;
  var state = {
    c: null,
    altValue: null,
    maxValue: null,

    get current() { return this.c; },
    get max() { return this.maxValue; },
    get alt() { return this.altValue; },

    set max(e) { this.maxValue = e; },
    set alt(e) { this.altValue = e; },
    set current(e) {

      if (this.c !== null) {
        // Remove class from current
        (images_compiled[this.c].target).classList.remove('expand');
      }

      if (e === null) {
        debug(4);

        // Collapse Lightbox
        if (document.getElementById(instance.options.lightboxId)) {
          (images_compiled[this.c].target).classList.remove('expand');
          document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.remove(instance.options.activeClass);
          (document.getElementById(instance.options.lightboxId).parentNode).removeChild(document.getElementById(instance.options.lightboxId));
        }
        this.c = e;
        return;
      }

      // Change current element, update lightbox
      this.c = e;
      var lightbox = document.getElementById(instance.options.lightboxId),
          res;

      // Check lightbox exists, if so change the image src
      if (lightbox) {
        var image = images_compiled[e].image.src;
        if (instance.options.galleryFolder !== null) {
          var filter = image.match(/([^\/]*)/g).filter(Boolean);
          image = image.replace(filter[filter.length - 2], imageSizes(instance.options.galleryFolder));
        }
        lightbox.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = image;

        if (instance.options.showAlt) {
          debug(7);
          lightbox.getElementsByClassName(instance.options.lightboxId + '__alt')[0].innerHTML = images_compiled[e].alt;
        }

        if (instance.options.showMax && this.max > 1) {
          debug(8);
          lightbox.getElementsByClassName(instance.options.lightboxId + '__num')[0].innerHTML = (images_compiled[e].index + 1) + '/' + this.max;
        }

      } else {
        res = generateExpand(images_compiled[e]);
      }

      // Add active class
      if (res) {
        (images_compiled[e].target).classList.add('expand');
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.add(instance.options.lightboxId);
      }
    }
  };

  // Setup light box
  function setupLightbox() {
    var images;

    images = container.getElementsByTagName('img');

    if (instance.options.limit !== null) {
      var tmp = [];
      for (var i = 0, length = images.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (i < instance.options.limit) {
          tmp.push(images[i]);
        }
      }
      images = tmp;
    }

    if (images.length < 1 || images === undefined) {
      error(3);
      return;
    }

    try {
      images_compiled = Array.from(images, function(el) {
        // Generate array of objects containing image information
        instance.images_count++;
        return {
          target: function() {
            if (el.parentElement.nodeName === 'A') {
              return el.parentElement;
            }
            return el;
          }(),
          index: instance.images_count,
          alt: ((el.alt) ? el.alt : ''),
          image: function() {
            // If class put on an A link then find the image
            if (el.tagName === 'A') {
              return el.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
            } else {
              return el;
            }
          }()
        };
      });
    } catch(e) {
      // Issue with generating array
      error(2, e);
    }

    debug(2, images_compiled.length);

    // Add image click event
    images_compiled.forEach(function(el) {
      if (el !== null) {
        var elm = el.target;

        elm.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          if (elm.nodeName === 'A') {
            e.preventDefault();
          }

          instance.active = true;
          if (state.current === el.index) {
            state.current = null;
            return;
          }
          state.current = el.index;
          state.alt = el.alt;
        });
      }
    });
    state.max = images_compiled.length;
  }

  function generateExpand(img) {

    // Generate lightbox HTML and append
    var html = buildHTML(instance.options.html);
    instance.events = {
      EventClose: function(evt) {
        if (evt !== undefined) {
          evt.stopPropagation();
        }
        instance.active = false;
        state.current = null;
      },
      EventLeft: function(evt) {
        if (evt !== undefined) {
          evt.stopPropagation();
        }
        if (state.current !== 0 && state.max > 1) {
          state.current = state.current - 1;
        } else {
          state.current = instance.images_count;
        }
      },
      EventRight: function(evt) {
        if (evt !== undefined) {
          evt.stopPropagation();
        }
        if (state.current !== instance.images_count && state.max > 1) {
          state.current = state.current + 1;
        } else {
          state.current = 0;
        }
      },
      EventClass: function(evt) {
        var arg = (evt.dataset.hover).replace(/ /g,''),
            args = (arg.match(/[^(]*/g).filter(Boolean))[1].match(/(?:([^,()]+)?)+/g).filter(Boolean),
            target = args[0].objectType(),
            action = args[1].match(/^(.*):(.*)/).filter(Boolean);

        switch(action[1]) {
          case 'add':
            // Add class
            target.classList.add(action[2]);
          break;
          case 'remove':
           // Remove class
           target.classList.remove(action[2]);
          break;
          case 'toggle':
            target.classList.add(action[2]);
            evt.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
              target.classList.remove(action[2]);
            });
          break;
          default:
            // Error
            error(7);
          break;
        }
      }
    };

    // Lightbox is active
    instance.active = true;

    // Assign event listeners
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(html.querySelectorAll('[data-click]'), function (e) {
      e.addEventListener('click', instance.events[eventName(e.dataset.click)]);
    });
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(html.querySelectorAll('[data-hover]'), function (e) {
      e.addEventListener('mouseover', function() { instance.events[eventName(e.dataset.hover)](e); });
    });

    // Insert lightbox into website
    var appendTo = (instance.options.appendTo).objectType();
    if (appendTo === null || (instance.options.appendTo).objectType() === undefined) {
      error(5, [instance.options.appendTo]);
      return false;
    }
    debug(5, ['id', instance.options.imagesContainer]);

    appendTo.insertBefore(html, appendTo.firstChild);
    return true;
  }

  MarvLightbox.prototype.current = function() {
    console.log(state);
  };

}());
```

As I said above though the `state` object appears to be shared between both instances, it should be unique.

Comment: Your issue may lie with `this.MarvLightbox =`

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies at *instance* i think:

```
var instance = null;
MarvLightbox = function() {
  instance = this;
```

So whenever a new Lightbox is created, instance points to it. This also applies to asynchronous callback functions which will all point to the last instead of the current instance. You may scope instance locally:

```
var instance=this;
```

Same applies to state:

```
MarvLightbox.prototype.current = function() {
  console.log(this.state); //make it an objects property, not global
};
```